# Peculiar results. #1-13 The C Programming Language Book

Tags: c

Question 1-13 of the 'The C Programming Language' book by K&R asks the reader to create a program that will make a histogram of words by length. The words are to be input by the user.

I've tried to create a program that will store how many words of each length their our then print out the int value of each array block before dealing with the histogram. No matter how much I fiddle around with this program it will always give me one of two results; either "1", or what I assume to be an array address? "6422476". Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GREATEST 10

int main(void){
    int c, word=0;
    int word_count[GREATEST];

    /*set all values in word_count to 0*/
    for(int i=0; i<GREATEST; i++){
        word_count[i]=0;
    }

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c != ' '){
            ++word;
        } else{
            word_count[word-1]=+1;
            word=0;
       }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<GREATEST; j++){
        printf("\n%d", word_count[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) You can get rid of the first loop by just doing `int word_count[GREATEST] = {0};` 2) `word_count[word-1] += 1;` will cause you trouble if `word` is equal to `0`, say if the first character input is a space; 3) You never count the final word; 4) You'll include newlines, periods, and other non-letter characters in your word count.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths My only question is to your third point, wouldn't 

 for(int j=0; j<GREATEST; j++) loop 10 times going 0-9 which would be all the word lengths?

Comment: That loop prints the histogram, it has nothing to do with counting words. You only count a word when you encounter a space. Unless the last character you read is a space, `word_count[word-1] += 1;` will not be executed for the final word, so it won't be counted.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good reason why you'd always get 1. Observe that

```
word_count[word-1]=+1; // This assigns to the value "+1"!`
```

should be

```
word_count[word-1]+=1; // This increments your array item`
```

It's a bugger what compiles in C :).

Comment: `=+` used to be an operator in ancient C! Also, these operators could be, once upon a time, written with whitespace in them as in `+ =`.

Comment: See here: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html   Quote: 
*"In B and early C, the operator was spelled =+ instead of += ; this mistake, repaired in 1976, was induced by a seductively easy way of handling the first form in B's lexical analyzer."*  Straight from Dennis Ritchie.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with either the correct `+=` or the 'not correct' `=+` and both gave the same output:

```
a bb bb ccc ccc ccc dddd dddd dddd dddd qwertyuiop eeeee

1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 1

a bb bb ccc ccc ccc dddd dddd dddd dddd qwertyuiop eeeee

1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

However both dropped the last word entered - zero for a 5 character length word. I think this is because you exit the while loop on an `EOF` such as `ctrl + D` and whatever had been entered since the last space `' '` is not processed.

Also if the user enters 'words' or groups of 'words' separated by spaces on more than one line the results are not correct. These 'options' for entering words makes it harder to process input consistently.

You might do better to instruct the user to enter one word at a time and reject input that contains a space.
This makes it easier to control the input and process all words entered.

Here is a code snippet for input using a buffer to hold input. 
The buffer size, the histogram array and the maximum allowable word length are all set using a static variable `maxlen`.

```
/* tell user what to enter */
printf("Type one word at a time (hit enter after each word)\nType 99 to finish\n");

/* get lines of input */
while ((fgets(buff, maxlen ,stdin)) != NULL) {
    /* test for '99' end code */
    if(strncmp(buff, "99", 2) == 0) break;
    /* test for any spaces in input -if so ignore input & print message */
    if(strstr(buff, " ") != NULL ) {
        printf("Enter one word at a time - then hit enter\n");
        } else {
        /* else get size of word (-1 for newline)  & increment appropriate counter */
        length = strlen(buff) - 1;
        hist[length]++;
    }
 }
```

The buffer was setup like this

```
char *buff = malloc(maxlen + 1);
```

and must be free'd once input is complete

```
free(buff);
```